# How to use findviewbyid other class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm try to this Kotlin code:

```
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(toast: String) {
        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview) // <-- problem
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Log.d("TAG", "message")
    }
}
```

Why it's not work? How can I fix this?

It may be a really basic problem, but I'm not an app developer. I do not know the scope of this language.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**findViewById()** is the method of Activity or Fragment.
You could pass the webview reference from parent activity or fragment and use in **showToast()** method.

class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context, private val web: WebView) {
}

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
I still haven't solved the problem, but now I know the concept that caused the problem. :) thx

Comment: You can also pass activity or fragment reference to WebAppInterface and use that reference to use findViewById(). If mContext is activity reference then you can us as **(mContext as Activity).findViewById()**